Choosing Between Autoencoder with OC-SVM and Reconstruction Error for Anomaly Detection: Training Strategies and Considerations
I plan to use an autoencoder and One-class SVM (OC SVM) for anomaly detection.
So there are 2 strategies:

train the autoencoder, and use the encoder output (as reduced dimension) to train an OC SVM

OR

use the whole trained autoencoder, calculate the reconstruction error, and use that with a threshold to detect an anomaly.

In the first approach, the goal of using an autoencoder is to reduce dimensionality.  in this case, if the model can reconstruct even anomalies that should be better. otherwise, the encoder might not have any information about the anomaly, and it reconstructs something that looks like normal data without the anomaly part. By inputting that kind of encoded vector, the trained OC SVM model will not be able to differentiate that from normal data. right?
But in the second approach, it should be other way around. Ideally, the model should not be able reconstruct the abnormal part and as a result the reconstruction error will be high.
so, it seems like these two approaches have kind of opposite way of finding the same thing, right ? so there training strategy should be different, right ?
is my thinking correct ?
